# New at phyton, but i need to insert this function in code

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I tried to make discord bot with discord python library, and i founded interesting code that sends message righ to your dm, while joining the server, but i have problems with connection it to my main code.

```
@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    await member.create_dm()
    await member.dm_channel.send(
        f'some text'
    )
```

I need to insert this function into this code

```
import discord
from discord import utils
 
import config

class MyClient(discord.Client):
    async def on_ready(self):
        print('Logged on as {0}!'.format(self.user))
 
    async def on_raw_reaction_add(self, payload):
        if payload.message_id == config.POST_ID:
            channel = self.get_channel(payload.channel_id) # получаем объект канала
            message = await channel.fetch_message(payload.message_id) # получаем объект сообщения
            member = utils.get(message.guild.members, id=payload.user_id) # получаем объект пользователя который поставил реакцию
 
            try:
                emoji = str(payload.emoji) # эмоджик который выбрал юзер
                role = utils.get(message.guild.roles, id=config.ROLES[emoji]) # объект выбранной роли (если есть)
            
                if(len([i for i in member.roles if i.id not in config.EXCROLES]) <= config.MAX_ROLES_PER_USER):
                    await member.add_roles(role)
                    print('[SUCCESS] User {0.display_name} has been granted with role {1.name}'.format(member, role))
                else:
                    await message.remove_reaction(payload.emoji, member)
                    print('[ERROR] Too many roles for user {0.display_name}'.format(member))
            
            except KeyError as e:
                print('[ERROR] KeyError, no role found for ' + emoji)
            except Exception as e:
                print(repr(e))
 
    async def on_raw_reaction_remove(self, payload):
        channel = self.get_channel(payload.channel_id) # получаем объект канала
        message = await channel.fetch_message(payload.message_id) # получаем объект сообщения
        member = utils.get(message.guild.members, id=payload.user_id) # получаем объект пользователя который поставил реакцию
 
        try:
            emoji = str(payload.emoji) # эмоджик который выбрал юзер
            role = utils.get(message.guild.roles, id=config.ROLES[emoji]) # объект выбранной роли (если есть)
 
            await member.remove_roles(role)
            print('[SUCCESS] Role {1.name} has been remove for user {0.display_name}'.format(member, role))
 
        except KeyError as e:
            print('[ERROR] KeyError, no role found for ' + emoji)
        except Exception as e:
            print(repr(e))

# RUN
client = MyClient()
client.run(config.TOKEN)
```

please help)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Make sure you give a descriptive title to your question. Also, try to add the exact error/problem you are facing preferably with a stack trace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just like the other `async def`'s in your `MyClient` class, just insert your first code snippet in there, without the decorator of course.

Here is what it should look like:

```py
import discord
from discord import utils
 
import config

class MyClient(discord.Client):
    async def on_ready(self):
        print('Logged on as {0}!'.format(self.user))
 
    async def on_raw_reaction_add(self, payload):
        if payload.message_id == config.POST_ID:
            channel = self.get_channel(payload.channel_id) # получаем объект канала
            message = await channel.fetch_message(payload.message_id) # получаем объект сообщения
            member = utils.get(message.guild.members, id=payload.user_id) # получаем объект пользователя который поставил реакцию
 
            try:
                emoji = str(payload.emoji) # эмоджик который выбрал юзер
                role = utils.get(message.guild.roles, id=config.ROLES[emoji]) # объект выбранной роли (если есть)
            
                if(len([i for i in member.roles if i.id not in config.EXCROLES]) <= config.MAX_ROLES_PER_USER):
                    await member.add_roles(role)
                    print('[SUCCESS] User {0.display_name} has been granted with role {1.name}'.format(member, role))
                else:
                    await message.remove_reaction(payload.emoji, member)
                    print('[ERROR] Too many roles for user {0.display_name}'.format(member))
            
            except KeyError as e:
                print('[ERROR] KeyError, no role found for ' + emoji)
            except Exception as e:
                print(repr(e))
 
    async def on_raw_reaction_remove(self, payload):
        channel = self.get_channel(payload.channel_id) # получаем объект канала
        message = await channel.fetch_message(payload.message_id) # получаем объект сообщения
        member = utils.get(message.guild.members, id=payload.user_id) # получаем объект пользователя который поставил реакцию
 
        try:
            emoji = str(payload.emoji) # эмоджик который выбрал юзер
            role = utils.get(message.guild.roles, id=config.ROLES[emoji]) # объект выбранной роли (если есть)
 
            await member.remove_roles(role)
            print('[SUCCESS] Role {1.name} has been remove for user {0.display_name}'.format(member, role))
 
        except KeyError as e:
            print('[ERROR] KeyError, no role found for ' + emoji)
        except Exception as e:
            print(repr(e))

    async def on_member_join(member):
        await member.create_dm()
        await member.dm_channel.send(f'some text')

# RUN
client = MyClient()
client.run(config.TOKEN)
```